# Displaying a Place Description on Google Places API for iOS

Tags: ios, google-places-api

My apologies if this has been answered already. I cannot find it and I'm very new to the GooglePlaces API for iOS.

Question: How do I get a place's description using the Places API and display on an iOS app?

I'm not sure if this is even possible but I'd like to find out. Please see the attached image as to what I mean by place "description."

[Google Place Description Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diWxR.png)

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -5):

You have to make **Place Details request** which is an HTTP URL of the following form with required *parameter*:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY

*key* (YOUR_API_KEY) — Your application's API key. This key identifies your application for purposes of quota management and so that places added from your application are made immediately available to your app.

*placeid* (ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4) — A textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place, returned from a Place Search. For more information about place IDs, see the place ID overview.
OR
*reference* — A textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place, returned from a Place Search.

You can request output in JSON or XML format;

All above info from below site, **please go through it**:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: place details doesn't return a place description