# Google Places API Place Description/Summary

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, http, google-places-api

Using the Google Places API I cannot seem to get the description of a place whether through a nearby_search or a details_search. Please look at the attached picture for what I am wanting to pull from the JSON. This information must be coming from somewhere, it's just a question of where.

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcEWs.png):
[image]

This has been asked here: [Displaying a Place Description on Google Places API for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193088/displaying-a-place-description-on-google-places-api-for-ios) but the answers are not adequate and link to documentation that I've read many times over and can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the mentioned description/summary is not available via the Places API at the moment.

There is a corresponding feature request in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827225

Please star the feature request to express your interest and subscribe to further notifications from Google.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is the `review_summary` field, part of the `extensions` parameter which was unfortunately [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PremiumData) a little over a month ago.

You could try HTML parsing the [`section-editorial`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Is6.png) div class.

Comment: I also have seen the review summary, and I could be wrong, but I do think that the quick sentence description that I'm looking for is different than the review summary. Interesting point about parsing the HTML, however, it seems a little hacky, but I'll definitely give it a shot.

Comment: @mystackoverflow1212 did you ever manage to figure out how to get the data? i am in the same boat, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was added to the places API as [PlaceEditorialSummary](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#PlaceEditorialSummary) just [last month](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827225#comment36).

It is not yet in any of the SDKs, so you need to do a raw HTTP request to get the info. [Examples are here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#maps_http_places_details_fields-txt).

I couldn't find any issues tracking adding that field to the SDKs, so [I created one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258921198).