# where does Google Places description field come from?

Tags: google-places-api

I am aware that Google Places API does not provide a description field ([refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577246/google-places-api-place-description-summary)) but I wondering where they get the description field you can see in their Maps?

I do not see this field when I made query in FourSquare's API.

I have also tried searching for this description in the network requests tab but do not see any JSON objects with this data.

where does it come from?

[image: place]

Comment: You would need to ask Google that.  They clearly have the information internally, but they probably just decided not to expose it in the API.  (If you want to find out why, you could get a job at Google ... :-) )

Comment: I think this is quite off-topic. But I think that information is entered by the business that manages that Google business page. Maybe that's one of the reasons why Google hasn't made it easily accessible, because businesses could make up lies in this description. That would make Google (and their services/products) look stupid as they give us this information. (It gives us the wrong impression, as we might see Google as credible, but in fact, the description was written by the business-owner.